# How to correctly use SUBSTR, INSTR and or REPLACE in Oracle 11G

Tags: string, oracle, replace, oracle11g, substr

What I would like to do is getting the third string. in this example:

```
NL 123456789 TUE
```

that is changed in this example to a number:

```
2927 123456789 353620
```

to be (re)placed in the back. So behind the '2927'. I am wondering how to do this? The code that I have at the moment for getting this string is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generateISIN(
  countryCode Country.Code%TYPE,
  universityCode University.Code%TYPE,
  studentNumber VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  newStudentNumber VARCHAR2(50) := '';
BEGIN
 select country.code || ' ' || studentNumber || ' ' || university.code
 into newStudentNumber
 from country, university
 where country.code = countryCode
 and university.code = universityCode;
  dbms_output.put_line(newStudentNumber);

  RETURN newStudentNumber;
END generateISIN;
/
```

this is my select statement for getting the first example

```
select generateISIN('NL','TUE', '123456789') from dual;
```

and this is my second select statement that turns the string into numbers (did not put the code loop in here)

```
select CONVERT_STR_TO_NUMERIC(generateISIN('NL','TUE', '123456789')) from dual;
```

If it is not too much to ask. Please provide me an example with my given problem

I hope my question is not too vague

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give us some examples of your desired input/output.

Comment: NL 123456789 TUE must be changed to 

TUE NL 123456789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use [`INSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) and [`SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679) the following should do it:

```
SELECT SUBSTR (x, INSTR(x, ' ', 1, 2) +1) || ' ' ||
       SUBSTR (x, 1, INSTR(x, ' ') -1)    || ' ' ||
       SUBSTR (x, INSTR(x, ' ') +1, INSTR(x, ' ', 1, 2) -INSTR(x, ' '))
 FROM (SELECT 'NL 123456789 TUE' x 
         FROM dual);
```

Though I would rather use [`oracle regexp_replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('NL 123456789 TUE','(.+) (.+) (.+)','\3 \1 \2')
  FROM dual;
```

Check [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1155).

Comment: Perfect mate. The regular expression did it for me. Thanks for the help. I marked your awnser as the right given one